# Vue CLI 4 with bootstrap or Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, bootstrap-vue, vue-cli-3, vue-cli-4

Hey is it possible to use bootstrap or vuetify with Vue CLI 4 (Vue3)? I couldn't find any information on the vuetify site (says CLI 3 or higher) neither on the bootstrap site.

I tried to install it, but I got the WARN default exports are missing...

Comment: I do not think Vuetify v2 is compatible with Vue v3 (yet) ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can use vuetify in vue cli 3 & 4.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/#vue-cli-install

I tried this and it worked.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great, it worked for me as well. But I had to use vue 2 instead of vue 3! Thanks